# fill-region for rectangle selection?

Tags: emacs

I'd like to do something like fill-region, except that I want to select a rectangle region and wrap only the text inside it, and have it stay within the rectangle bounds. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** Ah, I *knew* I'd encountered this ability before.

The rectangle editing abilities in `cua` provide this feature.

So first enable `cua-selection-mode`. That's the good stuff in CUA without the copy/cut/paste key changes, so you might want it on permanently:

```
(cua-selection-mode 1)
```

And then <kbd>C-RET</kbd> to mark a corner, move point to the opposite corner, and <kbd>C-q</kbd> as normal to fill. <kbd>C-RET</kbd> again to exit the rectangle mode.

CUA's rectangle editing is pretty awesome. Read about it in the commentary of <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `cua-base` <kbd>RET</kbd>. Look for the "CUA rectangle support" heading.

**Original answer:**

```el
(defun my-fill-rectangle (start end)
  "`fill-region' within the confines of a rectangle."
  (interactive "*r")
  (let* ((indent-tabs-mode nil)
         (content (delete-extract-rectangle start end)))
    (goto-char start)
    (insert-rectangle
     (with-temp-buffer
       (setq indent-tabs-mode nil
             fill-column (length (car content)))
       (insert-rectangle content)
       (fill-region (point-min) (point-max))
       (goto-char (point-max))
       (move-to-column fill-column t)
       (extract-rectangle (point-min) (point))))))
```

Comment: It turns out that this isn't quite right, but it's a good beginning. I also realized that what I really want is a way to just paste into a rectangle (I'll edit my original post).  I'll post a solution if I figure it out.

Comment: At this point, maybe you should post a new question rather than changing the question?

Comment: It turns out that cua-text-fill-rectangle can serve the purpose of pasting into a rectangle.